# Is Ant made for AIX?

Tags: aix, ant

Is there an [ant](http://ant.apache.org/) version for AIX?

Comment: Ant is plain Java. Runs on anything with a JVM.

Comment: I think your question more or less is duplicating this topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/488490/apache-ant-setup-in-aix?newreg=d759cf9a937e46ab8ac3e001fa32edd7

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is now YES - I just packaged it :)

The basic install instructions will be to download the installp file via the wiki page at http://www.aixtools.net/index.php/ant, then use smitty install to install the file

(via the command line - assuming downloaded to $HOME/tmp use)

```
# inutoc $HOME/tmp
# installp -d $HOME/tmp aixtools.apache.ant.rte
```

Comment: p.s. - if you try it, and have problems I 'listen' on http://forums.rootvg.net/aixtools for issues, etc.. ASIS support, but I try and react within 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Quoting [Ant's download page](http://ant.apache.org/srcdownload.cgi):

> Ant is distributed as zip, tar.gz and tar.bz2 archives - the contents
>   are the same. Please note that the tar.* archives contain file names
>   longer than 100 characters and have been created using GNU tar
>   extensions. Thus they must be untarred with a GNU compatible version
>   of tar.

For more Stack Exchange guidance, see Svetlin's link: https://serverfault.com/a/515602 which essentially points you to [Ant's installation document](http://ant.apache.org/manual/install.html).

For future reference and/or posterity, here are some additional sites that provide software for AIX:

- [AIX Toolbox for Linux Applications](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html)
- [Bull AIX Freeware](http://www.bullfreeware.com/)